# Решил рассмотреть как можно совместить php и js и наткнулся на проблемку с экранированием

Tags: javascript, php

Есть база данных, но из нее удалены некоторые поля и при выводе информации выводятся и пустые строки **вероятнее всего не продуманность кода** но не думаю его переделывать, а хочу решить проблему на месте.
Проблему встретил при вложении php кода в javascript. Возможно я тугой, но перелопатив весь интернет мне попались варианты решения задачи - экранирование, но этот способ не работает т.к. php тоже видит эти же экранированные символы и выдает ошибку. Для работы с БД использовал RedBeanPHP Не судите строго, занимаюсь этим для себя и не очень давно)))

```
<script>
<?php
    $maxID = R::findLast($table);
?>
    var phpСod ="<?php $maxID["id"]; ?>";
    for(var i = phpCod; i >= 1; i--){
        console.log(i);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Вам необходимо просто добавить вывод переменной. `<?php echo $maxID['id']; ?>`

Comment: Это пробная функция.  Переменная используется в цикле как стартовая точка. Она не распознается никак.

Answer (score -1):

Нужно было создать отдельную функцию с php кодом, а дальше вызвать ее в js как строку

```
var phpcod = "<?php maxid($maxID); ?>";
```